# Setting environment variables in ubuntu production server and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my controller:

```
def email_signup
    email_address = params[:email_address]

    response = RestClient.post("https://api:#{ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY']}" \
                  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/#{ENV['MAILGUN_ALIAS']}/members",
                  :subscribed => true,
                  :address => email_address)
    redirect_to jobs_url, success: "Thanks for Signing Up!"

    rescue RestClient::BadRequest => e
      redirect_to jobs_url, error: e
 end
```

Works great in dev using dotenv gem. After deploying to the server, I added the new environment variables to /etc/environment and deployed with capistrano again to restart the app and the app is giving me a `RestClient::Unauthorized (401 Unauthorized):` when I try to call this action which makes me think the env. vars are not set.

From the server console if I cd in to the railsapp/current and run `ruby -e 'p ENV["MAILGUN_ALIAS"]'` then I can see the variable print correctly.

I have also tried exporting the variables in .bashrc which doesn't change the behavior.

Also, just FYI, I am using RVM on the server to set the ruby version.

What else can I try here?

Comment: Why not move MAILGUN_API_KEY and MAILGUN_ALIAS to the secrets file? Is there a reason it has to be environment variables?

Comment: I just tried adding these to secrets.yml and no change in behavior, I also did a redeploy with Capistrano to restart the app and webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Capistrano, have you set your .env in your `shared` folder?

`config/deploy.rb`:

```rb
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push(
  'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', '.env'
)
```

Then obviously make sure you have your `.env` file configured with your secrets in the `shared` folder on the server that runs your application.

Comment: Good call here. For others who might find this I ended up moving the dotenv-rails gem from the development group to the root of the gemfile then also manually adding .env to the config folder on the server, then adding the same environment variables I have locally.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is the other common mistake I always made when setting up production with dotenv! Good catch.